# How to get ancestors of a vertex of DAG in precedence order?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

For a given node in Directed Acyclic Graph I want to get list of all the ancestors of that node such that they are satisfying precedence order
[image]

Let this is an DAG representing tasks and and their precding order.

Now suppose I want to do work E. Then I have to do work [A, B] first.

Hence for input DAG and node E output should be [A, B].

I want an algorithm for this.

Comment: Do you want them in some kind of order (use Topological Sort) or just a list of all of the ones preceding (use depth or breadth first search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find ancestors of specific target vertex:

```
dfs(v):
    mark v as visited
    for every neighbor u of v:
        if u is unvisited:
            if u is target vertex:
                return true
            if dfs(u) is true:
                put u in result set
                return true
        else
            if u is in result set:
                return true
    return false

for every unvisited vertex v:
    if dfs(v) is true:
        put v in result set

return result set
```

O(V + E) time complexity.

---

[Topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting): That'll give you the required ordering for all the vertices in O(V + E) time complexity.

Comment: I know this but it gives order of all vertex but I want only A, B. Is there a way to get only A, B

Comment: @aquibnawaz Updated the solution for specific target  vertex.